# using atomic c++11 to implement a thread safe down counter to zero

Tags: multithreading, c++11, counter, atomic

I'm new to atomic techniques and try to implement a safe thread version for the follow code:

```
// say m_cnt is unsigned

void Counter::dec_counter()
{
    if(0==m_cnt)
       return;

    --m_cnt;
    if(0 == m_cnt)
    {
        // Do seomthing
    }
}
```

Every thread that calls dec_counter must decrement it by one and "Do something" should be done only one time - at when the counter is decremented to 0.
After fighting with it, I did the follow code that does it well (I think), but I wonder if this is the way to do it, or is there a better way. Thanks.

```
// m_cnt is std::atomic<unsigned> 

void Counter::dec_counter()
{
        // loop until decrement done
        unsigned uiExpectedValue;
        unsigned uiNewValue;
        do
        {
            uiExpectedValue = m_cnt.load();

            // if other thread already decremented it to 0, then do nothing.
            if (0 == uiExpectedValue)
                return;

            uiNewValue = uiExpectedValue - 1;

            // at the short time from doing 
            //     uiExpectedValue = m_cnt.load(); 
            // it is possible that another thread had decremented m_cnt, and it won't be equal here to uiExpectedValue,
            // thus the loop, to be sure we do a decrement
        } while (!m_cnt.compare_exchange_weak(uiExpectedValue, uiNewValue));

        // if we are here, that means we did decrement . so if it was to 0, then do something
        if (0 == uiNewValue)
        {
            // do something 
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with atomic is that only that one statement is atomic.

If you write

```
std::atomic<int> i {20}
...
if (!--i)
    ...
```

Then just 1 thread will enter the if.

However, if you split up the change and the test, then other threads can get into the gap, and you may get strange results:

```
std::atomic<int> i {20}
...
--i;
    // other thread(s) can modify i just here
if (!i)
    ...
```

Of course you can split the condition test for the decrement by using a local variable:

```
std::atomic<int> i {20}
...
int j=--i;
    // other thread(s) can modify i just here
if (!j)
    ...
```

All the simple math operations are generally efficiently supported for small atomics in c++

For more complex types and expressions, you need to use the read/modify/write member methods.

These allow you to read the current value, calculate the new value, and then call `compare_exchange_strong` or `compare_exchange_weak` say "if the value has not changed, then store my new value, otherwise give me the new current value" a a single atomic operation. You can stick this in a loop and keep recalculating the new value until you are lucky enough that your thread is the only writer. If there are not too many threads trying too often to change the value this is reasonably efficient as well.

Comment: Thanks @Gem Taylor. For more complex types you said - "These allow you to read... you can stick this in a loop .... " - is it actually the way I did  ,right?

Comment: But only if you use `compare_exchange_strong` to make it a single atomic operation. Split the steps up and you hit the same issues.